# 'Make test' fails on installing older version of Perl (5.18.4)

Tags: perl, ubuntu, installation, version, lamp

Error in building:

```
 "EISDIR" is not exported by the Errno module
Can't continue after import errors at run/switches.t line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at run/switches.t line 17.
FAILED--no leader found
```

Exit error:

```
ext/Errno/t/Errno ............................................. FAILED--Further testing stopped: No errno's are exported
make: *** [makefile:872: test] Error 29
```

I am attempting to install an older version of perl as I require it for the installation of a LAMP Stack that has not been updated for a while.

I am following the instructions here:

https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028572351-Installing-a-custom-version-of-Perl-locally

I run into these errors upon running the 'make test' command.

I am running on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and currently have Perl version 5.30.0.

Comment: hmmm. I have 5.18.2 (and 16 other versions) installed on a Dreamhost machine without issue except the Cwd test that fails because `/home` isn't readable. I also have 14 versions of Perl installed on Ubuntu 20.04.04LTS as well. I used `perlbrew` to install them, and it can and does apply patches, but I find this unlikely to be relevant in this case. In all* cases, `perl -MErrno=EISDIR -e1` works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this solves your problem, but before you compile older perls with current toolsets, use [Devel::PatchPerl](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::PatchPerl). ikegami mentioned `perlbrew` in his comment to the question: it's smart enough to do that step for you.

But, what happens when you try to run your application with recent Perls? That might be an easy thing to fix. Most new things are feature-gated or only available on request.